Short story in which the main character buys a robot psychotherapist to get rid of the obsessive desire to kill
The main character buys a robot psychotherapist to get rid of the obsessive desire to kill, but the robot is confused with a model for Martians.
I remember the content quite accurately, but I can't remember the title or author at all.

Hi, welcome to SF&F.  Where and when did you read this?  Was it in a magazine, an anthology or online?

I don't get it. What do martians have to do with this story?

My guess would be that it's tuned for the wrong kind of psychology.

"Bad Medicine" by Robert Sheckley available at the link. ISFDB page here originally published in Galaxy 1956
Homicidal customer seeking therapy machine

"That, sir, is the Rex Regenerator, built by General Motors. Isn't it handsome? It can go with any decor and opens up into a well-stocked bar. Your friends, family, loved ones need never know--"


"Will it cure a homicidal urge?" Caswell asked. "A strong one?"
"Absolutely. Don't confuse this with the little ten amp neurosis
models. This is a hefty, heavy-duty, twenty-five amp machine for a
really deep-rooted major condition."


Martian machine

"Haskins, I told you. I must have told you! That display Regenerator
was a Martian model. For giving mechanotherapy to Martians."


Thank you very much.

@Mio No problem - please click the checkmark when you have the chance and keep the questions coming
